# AppHarbor Add-on Yocto to Nano upgrade

Tags: appharbor

Is possible to upgrade the SQL Server database created with Yocto Add-on to the Nano plan without loosing data or it's a new database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change between those the Nano and Yocto plans freely, no data migration required. If you upgrade to one of the dedicated database plans, then you currently have to migrate data manually.